# Error Log records in SSAS

Tags: sql-server, error-handling, ssas

We are processing cubes every day in job activity monitor, But on weekends w are receving email notification like "cube processing hase been failed". Is there any way to maintain error logs (like in ssis) on cubes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The key mechanisms for maintaining error logs for Analysis Services are to either:

1. Keep track of the data stored in the **msmdsrv.log**.  It will be necessary to copy the log off before it gets overwritten.
2. If you are using Analysis Services 2005, 2008, or 2008 R2, you can generate your own trace events as noted in the **System-wide Trace file section** of the post Analysis Services Processing Best Practces at: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966525.aspx#EBAA
3. If you are using SQL Server 2012, you can use the **XEvents** feature as noted in the SSAS documentation Use SQL Server Extended Events (XEvents) to Monitor Analysis Services at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492139.aspx

Another approach is to use the SQL Server Profiler runnning in the background so that way you can record all events.  But this would be similar to the #2 option.

Also note that the #3 option (using XEvents) has the least impact on your Analysis Services server in terms of resource utilization.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174827.aspx), logging is configured through a number of server properties that define logging behaviour and locations.